# Default Record Owner

Tags: user

I deactivated a user and removed him as a default record owner for the records created by the guest users, but still when a new community user is created(person account) the deactivated user is the owner of that record.

I checked all the flows by retrieving in VS code and searching the user Id to see if he has been hard coded somewhere but that is not the case either. what could be the issue

Comment: Did you check if any workflowrules or Assignment rules were assigning the owner?

Comment: Yeah I checked there is no automation that is happening. However I got the solution to this, the user was a site contact to the community site and whenever any one self reigsters in the community site this user will be the owner, I just needed to change the  Site Contact.